# recursive JQuery function with self triggering Ajax Request

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have got a JQuery as:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function NewRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Admin/FileUpload.aspx/<- Hear is [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]->",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function GettingResponse(msg)
            {
                if(msg = 'Upload Completed SuccessFully')
                {
                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                    NewRequest();
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to call "GettingResponse" function Recursively,so that on each response from server I can show the client some text and then again Send a Request to server

I don't know whats getting wrong as I dont Know Ajax and Jquery as well..
any other solution to my requirment will also be good...

Comment: its very urgent..

@Erwin Thankyou Dear
I am new Hear

Comment: What kind of functionality do you want to create? You can call $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(); again.

Comment: @erwin Thankyou Dear For Yor response
else
{
   $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
   NewRequest();
}
in this  part of the code if msg is not == " Completed SuccessFully "
i want to send the same request request to the server again and then again..
till the msg = "Completed SuccessFully"

after first iteration the request should be self triggered
means it should not require any kind of user interaction

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call the `click` function again when it fails:

```
$('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        .....
        .....
        success: function GettingResponse(msg)
        {
            if(msg = 'Upload Completed SuccessFully')
            {
            }
            else
            {
                $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>').click();
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: its not working

i tried on your suggestion
its not creation the request recursively
and one more problem is that JQuery is not setting the text to the <Div id="myDiv"></Div>
on each response the text must be changed of Div Must be Changed
there is no error in my C# Code
.. i have tried it seperatly

Comment: my main object is to get 100 response on 100 self triggered Ajaxian Request
and each time i want to Show the text to User

Answer (score 0):

> $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>').click();

i tried this but did not work...
ny way i got the answer

@Erwin thankyou dear you you suggested a good thing that worked with some different task